# JQuery Vertical Slide Animation doesn't move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JQuery function that makes a nav bar slide up or down as you scroll vertically. The idea is to always keep the navbar 20 pixels from the top of the client window. When the user scrolls up or down, the nav bar slides till it is back to 20 pixels from the top of the client window.

**My Problem:** It just wont bloody move lol. What have I done wrong?

Here is my JSFiddle with JQuery code: http://jsfiddle.net/wLga8/

Here is my code:

```
function moveDistanceEaseIn( /*HTML Element*/ ele, /*int|float*/ dist, /*Function*/ funct )
{
   ele = $(ele);
   var min = dist*0.01;

   // kill an already running animation
   if (ele.data("animInterval"))
      clearInterval(ele.data("animInterval"));

   var step = function()
   {
      if (dist <= min)
      {
         ele.data("animInterval", false);
         clearInterval(interval);
         return;
      }

      var stepMove = dist*0.1;
      dist        -= stepMove;
      funct(ele, dist, stepMove);
   };

   var interval = setInterval(step, 30);
   ele.data("animInterval", interval);
}

function moveToPointEaseIn( /*HTML Element*/ ele, /*int|float*/ curPoint, /*int|float*/ point, /*Function*/ funct, /*bool*/ signed )
{
   ele      = $(ele);
   var dist = (signed == true) ? curPoint - point:Math.abs(curPoint - point);
   moveDistanceEaseIn(ele, dist, funct);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(window).scroll(function () 
   { 
      var nav = $("#aa");
      moveToPointEaseIn(nav, nav.position().top, $(window).scrollTop()+20, function(ele, dist, stepMove)
      {
         ele.css("top", ele.position().top+stepMove);
      }, true);
   });
});
```

And some example HTML:

```
<body style="height: 3000px;">
    <div id="aa" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 20px; width: 200px; height: 500px; background-color: red;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Added the code to your question.  Questions on SO should be self-contained.  This is in case other sites go down, and so that the question is more searchable.

Comment: do you mean like [this](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/). [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/wLga8/5/) a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain why your function isn't working. The fiddle wasn't set to use jquery, but even setting that has no effect.

However, this seems to do what you're after....

```
<body style="height: 3000px;">

<div id="aa" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 20px; width: 200px; height: 500px; background-color: red;">

</div>
```

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("#aa");
 $(window).scroll(function(){            
    $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, 20 );            
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wLga8/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will solve all of your problem, but these should at least get you up and running so you can debug your code further:

- Add the jQuery library to your fiddle (missing in the one you posted)
- The first time your `step` function runs, the values are negative: `-100` and `-1`.  This means your `<=` test will kill your animation on the first iteration

I hacked around this by changing this line:

```
if (dist <= min)
```

To this:

```
if (Math.abs(dist) <= Math.abs(min))
```

The animation still looks wrong, but at least it is animating :)

Here's the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLga8/4/